# Dynamic creation of Table layout that auto fits cells according to screen size.

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am trying to display 9 images on my screen in 3x3 matrix format so that it fits to screen perfectly.
I am able to get the desired result using xml, but I am not able to replicate the same by creating controls through code.
(3 columns fit to my screen perfectly but the rows are not resizing to fit to screen)
Please suggest a way through which I can create dynamic controls through code and get the desired results.

Note : I want everything to fit in my screen in a matrix format, but without scrollbars. (I was unable to achieve this using grid layout)

Here is my xml :

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/encrypt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/gear"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    .
    .//Same as row 1
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    .
    .//Same a row 1
    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

This produces an output in matrix format, resizing cells to fit to screen.

But I am not able to replicate the same result when I am creating controls through code. This is code that I am using :

```
    TableLayout simple_game = new TableLayout(this);
    simple_game.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        simple_game.addView(tr);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams trPara = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
        trPara.weight = 1f;
        trPara.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        tr.setLayoutParams(trPara);

        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageResource(I[i][j]);
            tr.addView(iv);
            TableRow.LayoutParams trPara2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
            trPara2.width = 1;
            trPara2.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            trPara2.weight = 1f;
            trPara2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            iv.setLayoutParams(trPara2); 
        }
    }

    setContentView(simple_game);
```

Using this code, the columns are resizing themselves to fit to screen but the rows are not resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is LinearLayout and the weight attribute.
You can:

1. Dynamically add a LinearLayout 'horizontal'.
2. Add 3 LinearLayout s 'vertical' to the horizontal layout.
3. Add 3 images to each of the vertical layouts.
4. Set the weight of each vertical layout to 1.
5. Set the weight of each image to 1.

Note: weight doesn't work well with grid layout until API level 21 or 22, so if that is your target grid layout might be the way to go.

[This explains creating layouts dynamically.](http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html)

Comment: LinearLayout works. Thanks a lot! 
 I dont know why TableLayout was not working when I created it dynamically. I tried various combination for LayoutParams yet I didn't succeed.